# How to self publish

Tags: publishing, self-publishing

Publishing my novel seems daunting. I'd like some advice. I realize it's a big subject but what is the first thing I should do to self-publish my novel?

Comment: Hey Melissa, that's a rather broad question. One could write a book to answer it. Also, the question has been answered many times. Just google "how to self-publish". Among the results will be: https://janefriedman.com/self-publish-your-book/ and https://blog.reedsy.com/guide/how-to-self-publish-a-book/

Comment: Melissa, the first thing you should do is read the two articles that I linked for you (and maybe look at some others that you find when you google "how to self-publish"). After you have thus gained a first understanding of how self-publishing works, you will be able to ask more specific questions that you can either google again or ask here. We want to help you, but we cannot write a how-to-self-publish article for everyone who comes here and wants to self-publish. You'll need to make a little bit of an effort and do a bit of reading and research yourself first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Draft 2 Digital, Smashwords, & Booksie are all good sites  to self publish.**

- Draft 2 Digital: Free(Full Access), Print/Ebook, Free ISBN
- Smashwords: Free(Full Access), Print/Ebook/Audio, Free ISBN
- Booksie: Free(limited Access), Ebooks Only, No ISBN

Comment: Are those apps or just websites?

Comment: Can you explain *why* OP should consider these services over any others? What makes them "good" compared to other such services?

Comment: I have updated answer to show why they are good options. There are no apps for them.